# Django2.1.7 project urls.py not working properly (giving 404 error)

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

Project main urls problem. my code example below

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('/', include('homepage.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

applicaiton setting

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'homepage',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

homepage urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello')
```

Result: 
[image]

But if I change main project urls like below

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('homepage.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

result is:

[image]

> How can i see http://localhost:8000/blog in http://localhost:8000/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct.

In the screenshot you are visiting `http://localhost:8000` - no `/` at the end. Django tells you that the path is `/`. So, the correct URL is `http://localhost:8000/`.

If you want Django to automatically redirect, use [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#append-slash) in `settings.py`.

If you don't want the redirect and don't want the `/` from the end, then use `path('', include('homepage.urls')),` in the main urls file.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('homepage.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, You are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

homepage urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', include('homepage.urls')),
]
```

main urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', include('homepage.urls')),
]
```

I hope that helps